# how to disable 'swipe down from the top to exit full screen' message

Tags: android

[image]

In immersive mode, The above image appears in my android application.
My device is rooted and I can use ADB Shell. 
I want to remove the message. help me.

Comment: refer to https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-x/moto-x-qa/how-to-disable-swipe-to-exit-screen-t2775339

Comment: please read my question...

Comment: you can't  as soon as you enter immersive mode/full screen you will trigger the message.

Comment: It is sad message...